# VS Code: Pug autocomplete class names

Tags: visual-studio-code, pug

I searched the web today to find the answer, but I couldn't find any solution to this problem.

I use BEM in all of my dev projects, so I deal with class names pretty often and their names repeat a lot. In Atom when I wrote Pug code it would suggest to me an already used class name in this document. It was very useful and simple feature.

I moved to VS Code not so long ago, but I couldn't find solution to make this work. Is there any extension or other way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I added this line of code to settings:

```
"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "never"
```

And it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "html": "pug"
 }
```